# A topology on the natural numbers: a set is closed if it contains the divisors of all its elements

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Is there a name of or a reference to the following topology on $X=\mathbb N$:

$A\subseteq X$ is closed if and only if
$n\in A\wedge m|n\implies m\in A$?

Comment: do you need specific properties?

Comment: @Riccardo: I'm interested of anything.

Comment: Well maybe you can find some references on Munkres general topology, If it was some specific properties one can reason. Anyway I don't know a particular name for this sorry:(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a poset $(P,\leq)$, an up-set is a subset $U\subseteq P$ such that if $a\in U$ and $a\leq b$, then $b\in U$. A down-set is a subset $D\subseteq P$ such that if $a\in D$ and $b\leq a$, then $b\in D$.

The [*Alexandrov topology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) on $P$ is the topology whose open sets are exactly the up-sets (equivalently, its closed sets are exactly the down-sets). The Alexandrov topology has the unusual property that an arbitrary intersection of open sets is open (equivalently, an arbitrary union of closed sets is closed). In fact, a $T_0$ topology with this property is always the Alexandrov topology on a poset (take the specialization order on its points).

Your example is the Alexandrov topology on the divisibility order $(\mathbb{N},|)$. A quick google search for "Alexandrov topology divisibility" led me to [this paper](http://www.uta.fi/sis/cis/research_groups/ntg/LAMA_2012_Topol.pdf), where this topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is considered, and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0063.pdf), where the generalization to arbitrary integral domains is considered. I'm sure there are many others.