# A topology similar to the divisor topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

There is a topology on $X=\{2,3,4,5,\dots\}$ called the [divisor topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_topology), where the sets $S_n=\{x\in X\,|\;x|n\}$ forms a base of the topology. There is a similar (maybe dual) topology on $X$ defined as a Kuratowski closure:
$$c(A)=\bigcup_{a\in A}S_a$$

As the divisor topology it is $T_0$ but not $T_1$. Does this topology have a name?

Comment: dual in what sense do you think?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma - I don't know, but there is a sence of duality, which is a very abstract idea.

Comment: Like primes are open in the divisor topology and closed in this one? (the singletons)

Comment: Didn't [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1817454/4280) answer your question? I get the same "poset" vibe.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma - I blame my bad memory on my age. It's the same topology.

Comment: I couldn't describe it differently, then as the ALexndroff poset topology for the divisiblilty po; or its reverse, which seems close to the divisor topology, so in that sense they're dual: as poset-topologies for opposite partial orders...